# How to test the significance of VAR model coefficients?

Tags: r

I'm running a VAR model using 'vars' package. I went through the pdf and tried to search online but could not find a way to test the significance of coefficients using VAR() formula.

Any hint?

Thanks,

Juan.

Comment: You should provide an example of what you're doing

Comment: I have 5 macro economic variables. I created a VAR model using VAR() formula. I just want to know if it is possible to test the significance of the coefficient of my model. Thanks.

Comment: I ran into this question and maybe you will find helpful information here: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/79

Comment: you should look for granger-cause test in vars package

Comment: If the model is assigned to some variable like `mod`, just use `summary(mod)`.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple in R:
restrict(model,thresh=2)
It re-estimates all the coefficients and keeps all coefficient above t>=2

Comment: Sir, good. But how it re-estimate and how it happens that some of insignificant variables become signficant?